# Find the value of C such that the area enclosed by the curves $y=cx^{2}$ and $y=−x^{2}+1$ is 1.

Tags: calculus

So I am assuming that setting the functions equal to each other leads to $\pm \frac1{\sqrt{c+1}}$, however when I subtract $cx^{2}$ from $1-x^{2}$ and integrate, I get a massive mess of values that I can't seem to solve for.

Answer (score 1):

You want to know what is the area between those two curves, so you have to consider the integral (the limits will be the intersection of the curves)
\begin{align}
A 
&= 
\int_{-1/\sqrt{c+1}}^{+1/\sqrt{c+1}} \left[(-x^2+1) - (cx^2)\right]dx.
\end{align}
Solve the integral and $A = 1$, and you will obtain $c$ such that the area is equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Given $cx^2=1-x^2$ --> $x=\pm\frac1{\sqrt{1+c}}$ (I'll refer to as +/- a)
$1-x^2$ is the top curve, $cx^2$ is the bottom curve
$$\int_{-a}^a 1-(1+c)x^2\ dx =1$$
$$x-\frac{1+c}3x^3 |^a_{-a} = 1$$
Plug stuff in and mess around with numbers a bit...
$$2a-\frac{a^{-2}}3(2a^3)=1$$
$$a=\frac34=\frac1{\sqrt{1+c}}$$
$$c=\frac79$$